# Firebase local server

Tags: firebase

I've just discovered Firebase. If I don't want a paid account, is there a way to run it on my own server?

Or if that's not possible is Firebase open source, so we can just use them to host?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firebase is a proprietary service (and is not open-source or public-source), with a free tier and several paid tiers. However, any data that you store in Firebase can be exported at any time.

Comment: Just to complement, I miss understood about the framework, this link helped me too: https://github.com/cben/mathdown/issues/4